multiplicities of poles and sums of rational functions on algebraic curves
I have an irreducible plane algebraic curve C, and a (non-zero) rational function r(x,y) of which I know that it is the sum of two univariate rational functions f(x) and g(y) when restricted to C, though I do not know f and g themselves. Furthermore, I have a point (s,t) on C which is a pole of both f and g. I am wondering whether and how information (an upper bound) on its multiplicities can be derived from r and the polynomial which defines C.
Does anybody have an idea? Or know a reference that could be helpful?
Many thanks for your help!
